# Multiple files upload using AngularJS and Spring Boot

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, angularjs-directive

I am trying to upload multiple files at a time using Spring Boot and AngularJS.

Spring Boot file

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =  MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )

public @ResponseBody boolean UploadFile(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = true) MultipartFile[] files){
```

Here I am getting the value of MultipartFile[] files as MultipartFile[0]@17615 instead of an array of MultipartFiles. The length of the array is 0.

HTML File

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile" name="filePath" ng-model="filePath" on-click="false" multiple required>
```

AngularJS file

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
            return {
               restrict: 'A',
               link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                  var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                  var modelSetter = model.assign;
                  
                  element.bind('change', function(){
                  scope.$apply(function(){
                     modelSetter(scope, element[0].files);
                     });
                  });
               }
            };
         }]);
      
         app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', 'growl', '$state', function ($http, growl, $state) {
            this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){            
               var fd = new FormData();

               for(let i=0;i<file.length;i++){
                  fd.append('file', file[i]);
              }
             
               $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                  transformRequest: angular.identity,
                  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
               })            
               .success(function(data, status, headers) {
                 .....
               })
               .error(function(error){
                   .....
               });
            }
         }]);
      
         app.controller('uploadauditfilectrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', '$cookieStore', function($scope, fileUpload, $cookieStore){
             $scope.uploadFile = function(){       
                   var file = this.myFile;
                   var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload/";
               fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            };
         }]);
```

Can anyone please tell me the mistake I am doing.

Comment: Show your full controller method

Comment: @AjayKumar Hey thanks for replying. I did not write anything yet in the controller. I checked the value of files[] by running app in debug mode. I tried doing files[0] which gives error. I just checked the length of files array is 0.

Comment: @AjayKumar Hey it is working now. Thank you for responding. My code is correct.